# Clean proof for showing $f^{-1}([a,\infty))$ measurable implies $f^{-1}([a,b))$ measurable

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

I wish to show that for $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}([a,\infty))$ measurable implies $f^{-1}([a,b))$  measurable

Looks fairly easy if  $f^{-1}([a,b))$  is one piece.

Suppose  $f^{-1}([a,b))$  is an interval $\implies f$ is injective, then $f^{-1}([a,b)) = f^{-1}([a,\infty)) \cap f^{-1}((-\infty,b))$.

Since $f^{-1}([a,\infty))$ measurable $\implies f^{-1}((-\infty,b))$ measurable, and finite intersection and complementation of measurable set is closed in the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, hence $f^{-1}([a,b)) = f^{-1}([a,\infty)) \cap f^{-1}((-\infty,b))$ is measurable.

Is there a clean way to write the proof in case when $f^{-1}([a,b))$ breaks off into little pieces? Or is it just brute force taking union of all intersection of the half spaces on $\mathbb{R}$ that makes up the little pieces?

Comment: $f^{-1}([a,b))=f^{-1}([a,\infty))\setminus f^{-1}([b,\infty))$ provided $a<b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $[a,\infty)\cap (\Bbb{R}\setminus [b,\infty))= [a,\infty)\cap(-\infty,b) = [a,b)$ if $a< b$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

Then $f^{-1}([a,b))=?$